# ООП php работа с классами

Tags: php, ооп

Небольшая неурядица возникла после прочтения ООП в php
то есть мне понятны такие конструкции

```
echo $this->property;
echo $this->method();
```

Но такие вещи логически не понятны, прошу пояснить

```
echo $this->property->method();
```

Если нужно что-либо уточнить в вопросе напишите

Comment: это значит `property` так же является объектом, `method` которого вы и вызываете, аналогичное есть и в других языках

Comment: можете накидать пример? чтобы детально разобрать

Comment: `public function __construct() { $this->property = new Some_Class(); }`, а дальше где-то в классе можно уже `$this->property->some_method()`

Comment: хмм интересно, спасибо

Comment: один объект вложен в другой $a->property = new B(), у вложенного объекта точно так же можно дергать методы...

Comment: Тоже самое, кстати, можно и с методами творить. Если результатом работы метода возвращать объект..... как пример в грубой форме https://ideone.com/NqNMRz ........ он включает в себя и то, что ворон описал тоже

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485441/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-php-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-this-name-name2-name3-save