# Что значит на ООП PHP запись: $this->name->name2->name3->save();?

Tags: php, ооп

`$this->name` — свойство, но что дальше? Т.е. как понимать такие длинные конструкции? Видел в коде фреймворков и в чужом коде, но никто в попадавшихся мне видеоуроках ни разу не показал такую длинную конструкцию и что именно в ней происходит.

Ещё пример: `$this->data->name = $name;` 
Что значит: `->data->name`

Comment: почитайте комменты [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485373/5079). Где-то должен быть нормальный ответ, но искать, если честно, лень )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это композиция, или ассоциация. Случай когда полем класса является другой клас, имеющий свои собственные поля и методы.

Например:

```
class foo
{
    public $nameFoo;

    public someMethod()
    {
        return "какое то значение";
    }
}

class bar
{
    public $nameBar;

    __construct()
    {
        $this->nameBar = new foo();
    }
}
```

Тогда обращение к полю `nameFoo` поля `nameBar` (являющегося объектом класса `foo`) будет выглядеть так:

```
$item = new bar();
//обращаемся к полю (nameFoo будет присвоена строка "присваиваемое значение")
$item->nameBar->nameFoo = "присваиваемое значение";
//обращаемся к методу (будет возвращена строка "какое то значение")
$item->nameBar->someMethod()
```

И таких вложенностей может быть много.

Comment: Всё ясно. Спасибо всем огромное :)

Comment: @Алексей @totorro Предположу, что не только класс является полем другого класса, а вообще ОБЪЕКТ является полем класса... как пример .. можно сделать ассоциативный массив, переконвертировать его в объект и присвоить его в поле класса.. как пример https://ideone.com/6WXLOl   ...вот я сделал объект из массива.... теперь этот объект можно впендюрить в `$this->field`

Comment: Алексей Шиманский - вам тоже спасибо :)

Answer (score 6):

В видеороках такого не рассказывают. Потому что авторы видеоуроков сами ничего не знают, а лишь как обезьяны повторяют выученные у другого такого же балбеса пару команд.

Объяснение при этом очень простое: в РНР ты всегда можешь обратиться к результату, возвращаемому переменной. Например, запись вида

```
$name = $array[1]["name"];
```

означает, что сначала мы обратились к переменной `$array[1]`, но она тоже представляет собой массив, и мы можем сразу обратиться к его элементу `["name"]`

То же самое и с объектами. Если выражение возвращает объект, то мы можем пририсовать стрелочку и обратиться к его свойству или методу. И так до бесконечности. По-английски это называется method chaining, то есть нанизывание одного метода на другой. Например в PDO можно написать так:

```
$id = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO t VALUES(NULL)")->insertId();
```

Соответственно, написать `$this->data->name` можно только если `data` - это объект.